# Best practise for handling form submission in controllers

Tags: php, model-view-controller, forms, controllers

Lets say for example I am creating a an online shop. I have a controller called products and within that controller I have a function called create_product. Create_product calls a view that displays a form where users get to enter new products into the database.

When the user fills in the form to create a product, should I send the action back to the create_product controller and handle it with an IF statement? or offload to another function?

Example

```
<form method="post" action="www.example.dev/products/create_product/add"> 
//the above form would post back to the original controller

function create_product()
{
    if(uri->segment(3) == "add")
    {
        //call a model to do all the database stuff
    }

    load->view->create_product_form;
}
```

Is this the best way to handle this or should I be passing it off to another function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't cram a ton of stuff in one function using the URI segment to filter it. createProduct() can list the products available for creation (in a CRUD format, I assume), and the submission of the form should ping another controller with the POSTed data. Perhaps insertProduct(), where the data is sanitized and sent to the model for insertion to the database.

Separation of concerns! Keep the functions as separate as possible with good descriptors for the names of the functions.

Comment: Cheers Kyle, I like this method. I knew what I was doing wasn't the best way to do it but wasn't sure of which way to go.This makes so much sense :)

Comment: No problem. On a side note, be sure to use site_url() or whatever function your MVC package allows to keep the POSTing URLs clean. Your code looks like CodeIgniter, so that's why I suggested site_url().

Comment: Yeah I do use a base_url type function. I used to use codeigniter but currently adopting FuelPHP

Answer (score 1):

I (personally) would have a function that set the form parameters and "launch" the view with that form, and another function used to validate and call the model to put the values of that form into the database.  I believe that is really up to you, but the code would be cleaner if you divide the controller with several functions depending on what they actually do.

Answer (score 0):

I like the way symfony deals with forms & form submission. It is in one function (action)

simplified code:

```
executeCreate() {
$this->form = new Form()
if($r->isMethod('POST')) {
    //handle submission
    bind();
    save();
}
```